# Show that there can be no trail in $G$ that contains all edges.

Tags: graph-theory, advice

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph. Assume that $G$ contains at least three vertices with an odd degree. Show that there can be no trail in $G$ that contains all edges.

---

First I checked the definition of a trail; that is a walk that does *not* contain any edge more than once.
I tried reasoning by contradiction, assuming that there is a trail that contains all edges. Then there should exist a trail s.t. $v_0\rightarrow v_1 \rightarrow \dots \rightarrow v_n$ where every edge is unique. However, I am stuck here.

Could anyone please give me a hint to this problem and most of all **give me advice on how to approach these kind of graph theory proofs in general**? Thank you in advance!

Comment: For any vertex $v$ other than $v_0$ or $v_n$, how many edges in your trail meet $v$?

Comment: @NateEldredge Two I would say? One to 'enter the node' and one to 'leave it'?

Comment: Or four, if you visit twice. Or six. Or …

Comment: See Euler Path. This may be helpful - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NPXqUiLstUw

Comment: Could anyone of you also please comment on how you usually approach these kind of, to me at least seemingly abstract, graph theory proofs in general? What steps do you take?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: Consider a vertex $v$ that is neither the first nor the last vertex of a trail $T$. $T$ may pass through $v$ more than once, but each time $T$ passes through $v$, it ‘uses up’ two edges incident at $v$: one on the way in, and one on the way out. If $T$ contains every edge of the graph, those must be all of the edges incident at $v$, so $v$ must have even degree.

I can’t really offer any general advice. In this problem the *at least* $3$ in the problem statement might suggest that with just two odd vertices there *could* be a trail that contains all of the edges, and a bit of experimentation with small graphs would tend to confirm that. You’d probably also discover just where on the trail the odd vertices always seem to end up, which could well point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you for your help! However, I do not yet see why the fact that $v$ should have an even degree implies that there can be no trail that contains all edges. Doesn't the statement only say that there should be at least 3 with an odd degree? How does that rule out the possibility of some $v$ having an even degree?

Comment: @rbm: If there’s a trail that contains every vertex, there can be two odd vertices. But you didn’t quite grasp the hint. It’s important that $v$ is **not** an endpoint of the trail: that’s why it must have even degree if $T$ contains every edge.

Comment: Ah! I think I finally get it. So, If I am right, since there are at least three vertices with an even degree, this means that there is also at least one vertex which is not an endpoint of $T$ that has an odd degree? Thanks again for being so kind to provide me with assistance.

Comment: @rbm: You mean ‘at least three vertices with **odd** degree’, but yes, that’s exactly the point: if $G$ has at least three odd vertices, at least one of them must be a non-endpoint of a trail that contains every vertex, and the trail must then miss at least one edge at that vertex.

Comment: Yes, that was what I meant. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @rbm: You’re very welcome.